# ML.NET: How to save model to a database?

Tags: ml.net

I run a ML.NET sample app , there is the code in the Program.cs :
…

```
Console.WriteLine(“Training model…”);
var model = pipeline.Fit(trainTestData.TrainSet);
```

…
i.e. every time the model trained and created.
The question: Is it possible to save the model in a database after it once trained and created and then load and reuse the saved one?
It can be saved to zip file and loaded and reused. But how to save/load it to database?

Comment: Is it SQL Server you're saving it to?

Comment: yes, it is SQL Server, yet it may be PostgreSQL

Comment: You can save with the `mlContext.Model.Save` method. It's usually saved as a zip file. I'm pretty sure you can save the file as a binary in either of those databases. For SQL Server you can use [FileStream](https://codingsight.com/storing-files-in-sql-database-using-filestream-part1/), though I don't think this works for Azure SQL.

Comment: Ok, it  can work, but only for SQL Server and only when it installed with FileStream feature and it is enabled. But for PostgreSQL it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

The model can be saved to a `MemoryStream`, then converted to a byte array and stored in the database.

```java
 using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

_mlContext.Model.Save(trainedModel, trainData.Schema, memoryStream);

_dbContext.Models.Add(new Model
{
    Data = stream.ToArray()
    // ...metadata
});
```

Save  (stream overload signature):

```java
// Summary:
//     Save a transformer model and the loader used to create its input data to the
//     stream.
//
// Parameters:
//   model:
//     The trained model to be saved. Note that this can be null, as a shorthand for
//     an empty transformer chain. Upon loading with Microsoft.ML.ModelOperationsCatalog.LoadWithDataLoader(System.IO.Stream,Microsoft.ML.IDataLoader{Microsoft.ML.Data.IMultiStreamSource}@)
//     the returned value will be an empty Microsoft.ML.Data.TransformerChain`1.
//
//   loader:
//     The loader that was used to create data to train the model.
//
//   stream:
//     A writeable, seekable stream to save to.
public void Save<TSource>(ITransformer model, IDataLoader<TSource> loader, Stream stream)
```